# How to let user know, an ImageView is clickable

Tags: android, imageview

I have an ImageView(see image below), which is clickable. When the user clicks on the ImageView, he gets redirected to website. This is all running fine.

My question is, how to let user know, he can click the image, how to make this feature visible?

I can add text under the image, but thats not, what i want. I would like some small icon or window(like dialog), which can be closed.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: create help screen or provide help some other way

Comment: you can create a frame layout and put both imageview and a textview.in the textview you can write:"more info" or something like that

Comment: You may get a decent answer here but if not you might want to ask this on [the user experience part of this site](http://ux.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: try to give shadow in your image using photoshop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I searched and found [this](http://www.xatik.com/2012/12/03/add-an-android-help-overlay-to-your-application/). This is @kgandroid suggested.

I add a little bit of code:

```
private FrameLayout mFrame;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mFrame = new FrameLayout(this);
    mFrame.addView(LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_single_list_view, null));
    setContentView(mFrame);

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    boolean overlayShown = settings.getBoolean("overlayShown", false);
    if(!overlayShown){
        setupHelpOverlay();
    }
    ...
}

private void setupHelpOverlay(){

    final View tutView = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_detail_overlay, null);
    if(mFrame != null){
        mFrame.addView(tutView);
    }

    // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
    // All objects are from android.context.Context
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("overlayShown", true);

    // Commit the edits!
    editor.commit();

    Button btnDismiss = (Button) tutView.findViewById(R.id.button_overlay);
    btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            mFrame.removeView(tutView);
        }
    });
}
```

And the activity_deatil_overlay.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/transparent_gray" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/overlay_text"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_overlay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/overlay_button"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

On the first start, it shows help overlay.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can check by bellow:

```
imageViewObject.isClickable();
```

Comment: Please read the question! Thats not what i am looking for. I know that the ImageView is clickable. But the user doesnt see this.

Comment: I think they are more looking for a user interface solution. I think the technical side is working

Comment: oh. its and design issue. for that i cant help you. sorry.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could animate a small finger/hand icon tapping the image when the ImageView shows up to indicate the element is clickable.

Like this: http://cmsresources.windowsphone.com/windowsphone/en-us/How-to/wp7/block/gettingstarted-concept-tap-and-hold-gesture.png

Or you could use gradients and shadows to give the image a button look.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a bar around the Image and change its color when the image is pressed. So it looks like a button.